# Jest timeout when I try to save mongoose document

Tags: typescript, mongoose, jestjs, ts-jest, typegoose

Stack : Typescript, Typegoose, Jest, Mongo Memory Server

I'm trying to save a doc during a test but as soon as I'm trying to await the save, the test timeout.

I've setup the connection to the db previously

```
beforeAll(async () => {
  db = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL || "");
});
```

then I've defined my test

```
it("should create a verification token", async () => {
  const user = await userModel.create({
    username: "test",
    email: "test@test.com",
    password: "testtest123",
  });

  // modify 'user' here

  await user.save(); // Timeout on this line

  // some expect
}, 50000);
```

And even with 50000ms the test still timeout. Any help is welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: Is the model created on the same connection that is connected to the database? (in typegoose this is set via the `existingConnection` option); also is your model and test on the same version of mongoose? (this could be the case when the model is from a different package); also is the connection actually fully connected at that time?

Comment: Yes it's using the same one. Test and model use the same version of mongoose. And yes it's fully connected, all my other tests pass

Comment: Then i dont see any problems currently on why this would cause a timeout, could you maybe provide the use class / schema you are using?